# 24 VAC Irrigation Valve Oscillation?

Tags: solenoid-valve

Is there an oscillation happening when powering a 24 VAC irrigation valve? Since the solenoid is being driven by an alternating current (AC), does that mean it goes "on" and "off" at some points of its AC phase (e.g. at zero volt crossing) at a fast rate that no one really notices it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want irrigation valves closing and opening at a rate too fast for humans to notice. Are you asking about overshoot, hunting, hysteresis or something similar?

Comment: More likely mechanical inertia means that the valve can't react to each individual pulse (half cycle), but stays on until power is removed.

Comment: Your hyperthetical question makes little sense.  Give us a concrete example of what you are talking about, and maybe we can explain what is going on.  As it stands, this question needs to be closed because it is unclear what is being asked.

Comment: I think this is an on-topic question. Simplified, it is asking whether an AC solenoid opens and closes along with the AC sine wave.

Comment: I think the question should had been "Why I don't observe a chattering behavior in a 24VAC irrigation valve driven by an AC supply?"  At half phase of the ac cycle when it crosses 0 volt, what exactly happen to the solenoid and valve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many irrigation valves use a 24V AC solenoid to operate the valve. The valve is opened or closed by changing the position of a diaphragm or flap which allows or blocks water flow.

During the period of an AC waveform, the voltage of course changes, but the solenoid does not open and close the valve at that frequency because AC solenoids are designed to compensate for the fact that AC voltage crosses zero volts every cycle. It uses a shading coil for this:

> ... a shading coil is designed to obtain minimal pulsing in force. What this means is that the coil splits the pole into two separate parts which causes the flux of these parts to be out of phase. If not for this shading coil, the chattering sound that is commonly associated with AC solenoids would be more noticeable.

Source: [Ledex - Comparison of AC vs. DC Solenoids](http://www.ledex.com/solenoid-applications/ac-vs-dc-solenoids.html)

24 volts is a common choice for irrigation systems because it can utilize smaller gauge wires than say 12 volts, and AC is more suitable for longer distance cable runs, which are common in landscaping applications.

Comment: I wonder why they say that AC is more suitable for longer runs.

Comment: @Spehro I am paraphrasing that from memory, but I am not having luck finding a source. When it comes to buried low-voltage lines, the distance is probably less a factor than corrosion due to electrolysis, if I hazard a guess.

Comment: That would make sense, but as you say, distance isn't much of a factor-- unless they're considering the cost of ripping up 200' of corroded wire to replace it every decade or two.

Comment: Thanks for the Ledex link.  It mentioned and described about this shading coil that reduces this "chattering" behavior in an ac driven solenoid valve. A picture contains a thousand words.  It (or a video) would really help visualizing how this shading coil prevents chattering in an ac solenoid valve.

Comment: @user36712 There is an illustration at [this site](http://www.mromagazine.com/news/understanding-electrical-solenoids/1000107756/?&er=NA).

Comment: @JYelton Thanks for the link as it further explains about ac solenoid and its shading coil.  Now this really make me curious to see the inside of an actual 24VAC irrigation valve and what this shading coil looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Are you suggesting that it would open and close at mains frequency (actually it would be twice mains frequency, so 100Hz or 120Hz)? No, they don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting that it should open and close the valve since the solenoid is being driven by an alternating current (AC) as opposed to a direct non-changing DC current. We all know that it does not happen that way.  But why? An AC solenoid has a shading coil that prevents its plunger from collapsing by the virtue of induced magnetic field at zero volt crossing.

Answer (score 0):

The attraction force between the core and the solenoid really varies at double mains frequency, and it causes the valve to oscillate. It's audible, but not noticable in the water flow. The oscillation amplitude is much lower than the valve's working move distance.

I have had a washing machine with a 220V AC valve and I know what it sounds like.

Comment: As per "this site" link above suggested by jyelton, a buzzing (audible) AC solenoid is "screaming" at you to check its shading coil or clean its plunger path or else it would result to its coil burnout.

Comment: That was a Soviet Union AC solenoid without a shading coil. It was designed to work without a shading coil, so it's normal for it to sound this way.

Answer (score 0):

Chattering is an abnormal occurrence, and it will quickly tear up something, probably the solenoid valve.  There is no observable change in the hold-in force on the coils of the solenoid valve, because the wiring is done so that when one polarity reverses, so does the other (thinking of the assembly as a stator plus a "rotor").  So the result is always a positive holding force while the valve is energized.  Further, the coils are  generously designed so that the variations in the always-positive holding force are small compared to the average value of the force.  Think of a BIG lake with little ripples: the depth of the water hardly changes.  Here, the depth of the water is analogous to the LARGE holding force of the coil, and that LARGE force pulsates a little.  You either have a defective solenoid valve, or (much more likely) your voltage at the point of use is very much less than normal, and is in fact less than the minimum voltage required to operate the valve properly. Solenoid valves are very robust, and it is unlikely that yours has been damaged.  On the other hand, your point-of-use voltage could be unusably low just because you haven't got big enough (or short enough) supply wiring.  The ampacities routinely cataloged for wire assume a short distance from the source of supply; but if you are using the light-weight wire people often skimp on, or your power source is distant, or both, you will probably measure barely more than half as much voltage at the solenoid as you expect and want.  The solution is to beef up your electric power so that you actually deliver a voltage to the solenoid valve which is within its acceptable range.  Many low voltage loads are consequently high-current devices, which aggravates the problem.  But again, I'd give you 99-to-1 odds that you have low voltage at the solenoid valve.